# What is that void that the universe is growing into?

Tags: universe

We understand that this is the universe and it is essentially full of space and time, but what is on the outside of the universe, and isn't that nothing, something, and how far does that reach.

I.e. isn't that another aspect of the universe? For it to go into it, it must be something for it to go into it.

If I throw a ball through the air, the ball travels through air. If I throw a universe through the air so to speak, doesn't that have a characteristic, frame and limitation?

Comment: That's the simplest question mankind has encountered, and the simplest answer is : We don't know.

Comment: Additional dimensions can be added, but they don't necessarily make things easier to understand.

Comment: If someone is up to speed on the current state of *"we really don't know"* -ness, please feel free to add ***that*** as an answer.

Comment: @called2voyage I don't think this is really a duplicate of "Does our universe have to be embedded in a higher dimensional space?"

Comment: @EduardoSerra Present your case for how it is substantially different and I will consider reopening.

Comment: Cheeku that's not science! Definetly true Robert. @called2voyage, you misrepresented my question. My question is about the void and not fitting into some frame like a puppet! The yolk and the egg, not the shell and the person holding it! My question is about the void, not other dimensions or being embedded in anything. Like how we have a right brain and a left brain, what if the universe has 2 parts. Expanding scientific thinking...

Comment: @Thoth Present a model for how your suggested division/part of the universe that we are presently unaware of could exist without separate dimensions. You talk about throwing the universe through the air. The universe is a four-dimensional space, for it to experience motion there has to be some other dimension for it to experience motion in.